# Why is there "at character" (@) syntax for properties?

Tags: maven

This question has probably been asked before, but it is quite difficult to google.

I've seen this syntax in pom.xml files:

```xml
<version>@project.version@</version>
```

Paired `@` characters seem to be another way to refer to properties, but it is not mentioned in [Maven documentation for properties](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Properties). Why is there this syntax if we can refer to properties with `${property}`? Or maybe it is for something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The possible property delimiters are defined by the [maven-resources-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/resources-mojo.html#delimiters) (more exactly the [maven shared filtering module](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-filtering/)).

Using that `<delimiters>` configuration, you can even change (by adding or replacing) the delimiters to match whatever syntax you need to support.

So that is where it comes from technically, and couldn't find any text stating why it is used, but I guess is comes handy in the case you have two systems working on the same files (Maven and some pre- or post-build), or dealing with some legacy system working with the `@` as delimiter.

The commit adding the use of `@` comes from the initial commit gathering various ways of managing filtering in a shared component. In the JIRA issue refering to this commit: [MSHARED-46](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MSHARED-46), there is only few documentation about a generic intend, there is a link to a [Codehaus doc](https://web.archive.org/web/20091018143912/http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVEN/Resources+Handling+(common+component+maven-filtering)), retrieved thanks to the Internet Wayback Machine, as Codehaus is down now.

Comment: I don't think that commit added it, because there was already code that picked `@*@` up [here](https://github.com/apache/maven-shared/commit/4f452b8709e3fd4194c5084eab62ad042454c1fb#diff-c779cee6cd833f7560b2253c0a48b3d3L252), just in a much more programmatic way than a declarative way. It seems that that code was added with [an SVN conversion commit](https://github.com/apache/maven-shared/commit/6a5796fe6372e06e685d96533c99d1e4c0181c76), but also without documentation.

Comment: Oh, you're right, this comes from the first commit out of the sandbox. The SVN repo might give more info about the original location though.